# Perl-rename: regex for case-insensitive matching

Tags: regular-expression, perl, rename

`perl-rename 's/b(\d{2}A)/\1/' *` finds and renames every part of any file with

1. "b" followed by
2. 2 digits followed by
3. "A"

Is there an option or way to make the regular expression case-insensitive, i.e. also matches either an uppercase "B" for the first part and/or a lowercase "a" for the last part?

Comment: Can you provide some samples? its not clear what you mean by "an uppercase "A" for the first part and/or a lowercase "a" for the last part?"

Comment: Is `[aA]` what you're looking for?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes. The matching works then. If you provide your comment as an answer, I can mark it as solved.

Comment: @Inian I made a mistake with the "uppercase "A"". It should have been "B" instead. I genuinely thought the enumerated list was self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `s///` substitution command in Perl (and thus in the Perl `rename` command) has a flag `/i` to do case insensitive match. All you need to do is

```
perl-rename -n 's/b(\d{2}A)/\1/i' *.jpg
```

Remove the `-n` flag when you identify the files are renamed as expected. It only does a dry-run to show how the files will be eventually renamed.

To selectively allow case insensitive matching of one or several characters, use e.g. `[aA]` (will match either `a` or `A`).

Answer (score 2):

While the `/i` modifier is the most common and well-known answer, it should also be said that this can be modified inside the regex itself.

```sh
/(?i)b(\d{2}A)/
```

This can be useful for dynamically generated patterns, patterns saved in files, etc. Also, it can be "turned off" either by limiting it to a group (capturing or otherwise):

```sh
/(?:(?i)b(\d{2}A)) Foo Bar/ # the Foo Bar portion is still case-sensitive
```

Or by the fact that it's a modal setting, so you can switch it back off with a negation:

```sh
/(?i)b(\d{2}A)(?-i) Foo Bar/ # again only Foo Bar is case sensitive
```

Comment: Also `/sensitive(?i:insensitive)sensitive/`